# Converto whole text to ascii using haskell

Tags: haskell, ascii

I have text file with inputs, how I can convert it to ascii and vice versa?

```
abz
z?
9798122
```

these inputs would give this output:

```
9798122
12263
abz
```

First I read inputs from text file and have all lines, but I do not know how to convert whole line to ascii. Here is what I have so far:

```
asciiWords :: String -> String 
asciiWords = words

convertLines :: [String] -> IO ()
convertLines = mapM_ (putStrLn . asciiWords)

main = do 
  content <- readFile "input.txt" 
  let linesList = lines content
  convertLines linesList
```

Comment: What do you mean with "convert it to ASCII"? Furthermore by adding no separators, there is no direct way back. How would you for example convert `12122`? As `12 122`? Or like `121 22`?

Comment: in ASCII table a is 97, b is 98 and z is 122, then abz(input) should be 9798122(output) after converting it.

Comment: @Simas Willem is talking about the other way round. If you have "9798122" how would you get 'abz' back from that? Sure, you could treat it as "97 98 122", but you could equally treat it as "9 79 81 22"

Comment: Do you need ascii values of characters as a string? If not then you can just output a list of `Int`. Changed signature will `asciiWords :: String -> [Int]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Data.Char` module offers `ord` and `chr` for converting from a Unicode character to its codepoint and back.

```
ord :: Char -> Int
chr :: Int -> Char -- beware! partial function
```

The less mnemonic names `fromEnum` and `toEnum` are also available without any imports.

You will want to spend a little time thinking about what should happen to characters which are not in the ASCII range.